# Installing LibIconv using Homebrew in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: homebrew, ubuntu-20.04, libiconv, clamav

I’m running Ubuntu 20.04.1 on Hyper-V in Windows 10, and I need to install LibIconv (in order to install ClamAV through a Homebrew package).

When I run `brew install clamav` or `brew install libiconv` I get this:

```
libiconv: is not needed on Linux, where iconv.h is provided by glibc
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

So far, I’ve made sure I have all the other dependencies for ClamAV listed [here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/clamav). However, I’m having trouble installing LibIconv. I also made an attempt using [these](https://geeksww.com/tutorials/libraries/libiconv/installation/installing_libiconv_on_ubuntu_linux.php) instructions, but I don’t think I was successful because I still get that error above. I'm pretty new to the command line, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: The error message says it: GNU libiconv is not needed on glibc systems.
How about removing this dependency from the clamav recipe, for glibc (and musl libc) systems only?